# How to create INavigationService for WPF. Navigate with custom Windows loaded from XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm

**I'm trying to build a service that enables custom Windows to navigate in WPF**. I have previously saved in a XML giving a Action "Navigate" with a parameter string that contains the next custom Window. What I'm trying to do is to fire the button that is located in my Custom Window, read the string and give it my service that will navigate to another custom Window.

[image]

#### Difficulties what I have implementing this Service.

1. *NavigateWindow* doesn't help me to solve the problem.
2. *Frame* control doesn't help me to. This button can be in every place.
3. I didn't found like **PhoneApplicationFrame** in Windows Phone to navigate between Windows.
4. This give me a error.

   `NavigationWindow navigation = new NavigationWindow();
    navigation.Navigate(new Window1());`
5. And this too

   `NavigationWindow navigation = new NavigationWindow();
    navigation.Navigate(new Uri("/Window1.xaml"), UriKind.Relative);`

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationWindow is meant to work with Pages not Windows. Basically it creates a 'host' if you like, on which you then can navigate through your different pages. I learned this the hard way, even trying to build my own equivalent to NavigationService to make something like this work using only Windows. Eventually I trashed it all and went with using pages instead and never looked back. Implement your design using Pages instead, and it will all work beautifully.

Comment: Hi @ouflak, can you give me some reference/articles or tutorials to get started? thanks!

Comment: Interestingly this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), uses pages and gives a pretty nice example of the basic use. If your are used to working with Windows, you will pick this up very quickly. It's highly intuitive.

Comment: This topic is no longer available

Comment: Got another link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Thanks for letting me know! Plus one coming somewhere....